# How to resolve "your browser does not allow access to your computer's clipboard" on Google Docs?

Tags: chrome, clipboard

I'm trying to copy or paste some text, in Chrome, on Google Docs, and getting this error:

```
your browser does not allow access to your computer's clipboard
```

How to resolve it for Chrome ([this seems to be a resolution for Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard))?

(The reason I posted here is that this only happens to me on my linux/ubuntu - not on Windows)

Comment: I think this also happens in Debian 11 GNU\Linux on MS O365. When I try in Firefox, O365 gives me a message similar to the above suggesting that I use keyboard shortcuts. When I try in Google Chrome, I also get that message along with the recommendation to install this "Office Copy and Paste extension": https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-enable-copy-and-pa/ifbmcpbgkhlpfcodhjhdbllhiaomkdej I haven't tried that extension yet and I suspect it won't work for Google Docs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: copy the text to the clipboard as usual, and then use the shortcut shift+insert to paste it into Google Docs. Or ctrl+v.

There is another option: in Linux you can make a "special" kind of copy (it has a name, but I forgot it) by just highlighting the text and then using the middle mouse button to paste it. I'm quite used to it, because I usually work only on Linux, and I miss it when I have to use Windows :-)

Comment: Right now I'm trying to copy _from_ Google Docs, which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Strange. I've tried just now, selecting some text in Google Docs (using Chromium, the open source version of Chrome), pressing ctrl+c to copy and then using shift+insert in a terminal to paste it, and it worked. Does this work for you?

Comment: Hmm. It works from my desktop, but when I tried it yesterday from my laptop it didn't. I don't know what the difference is, both should be nigh-identical machines, OS wise.

Answer (score 0):

A problem that I have only experienced with my new PC with Windows 10.  However,  just found a solution on a German Website, that for the moment is working for me.   Go Ctr+Shift+N for an incognito page ... if Copy Paste works here then try deactivating some of your extensions.  Hope it works for you too.